# Как сделать сделать ссылку вида test.domen.com

Tags: хостинг

Как сделать сделать ссылку вида test.domen.com, то есть что бы перед названием домена было test. как например maps.google.com

Comment: на хостинге создаете субдомену и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду субдомены, которые стоят перед основным. Обычно создавать и настраивать их можно через панель управления хостинга. Т.е вы создаете субдомен и для него создается отдельно папка. Субдомены могут использовать например для создания мобильных версий сайта и так действительно проще  m.site.ru